# Iterating over set of feature classes and spatial join to create only one output?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, overlay, identity

I have a feature dataset with 50-some odd feature classes (polygon) that all have fields that I need to spatially join to one feature class (point).

So in the end, I only want one object with all of the necessary fields from all of the feature classes, so the final object will look somewhat like this:

Point Feature Class:

- Column 1: Point_FC_ID
- Column 2: Layer1_value
- Column 3: Layer2_value

...and so forth.

I don't want to have to create 50 some odd outputs for 50 some odd polygon feature classes.  Ideally I would like to just have my base set of inputs and only one output.

How can I do this?

So far... all I can think of is loading all of the feature classes ito the in_memory workspace and then joining all of the fields I want to one output object. I don't know if you can use the same input object as the output object in a spatial join. I would like to use Spatial Join because in side-by-side tests with the other Overlay GP tools, it performs the fastest.

I am using ArcGIS 10.6.1 and arcpy 2.7.